# Writing to a file in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm just trying to write into a .txt file in Objective C. Here is the code:

```
BOOL success = [str writeToFile:@"tmp/cool.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@"done writing!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"writing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

The output of this code is "The folder cool.txt does not exist". I dont understand this, since the ".txt" would deem it to be file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Into what directory are you writing?  If you haven't set that explicitly, there's a high probability it's not where you expect, and thus, the subdirectory tmp does not exist.  You have to ensure the entire path hierarchy exists before writing to the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a demo for you, assume that you use iOS.

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp"]; //get tmp path
NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cool.txt"];

NSString *str = @"hello world";
NSError *error;
[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", str1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you use iOS as the platform...

1. You need to first get application's document directory so that you can write into that directory (you can use library or temporary directory but document directory is most common)
2. You have to make sure that 'tmp' directory exists under the document directory.